# IBMI Iseries v7r3 - How to Connect with Script to Send Command and Get Output

Tags: ibm-midrange

Is there a way to write a script (python or java) that can connect to IBMi to run command and get the output, or maybe can be something like shell scripting (.sh) in linux. For example, in order to view the  authorization value of an object, in green screen I will run WRKOBJ [OBJNAME] and 5 to display the information for each library.

My challenging here is I need to get the value for few hundred objects, so I am thinking if there is a script that I can automate the process and output the value to a file.

Your help with any suggestion and references are very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some views and table functions are available with sql. This is called IBM i services.
I think you can get most of the infos you want from them
Check the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzajq/rzajqservicessecurity.htm)

Comment: I have go through the document and it looks good. Do you have any reference on how to/ where to execute the query? I am new to IBMi so not really know how I can execute the query.

Comment: I see you don't have PHP so maybe with java with this [jdbc driver](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) and this [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzaha/rzahajdbcdriver.htm)

Comment: You also can find a linux ODBC driver [there](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions), you only need ACS Linux App Pkg [configuration](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-iaccess-linux-odbc-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

can you run PHP on your IBM i?  Here is a PHP script which does the following:

- reads 3 parameters from the `querystring`. `objName`, `objLib`, `objType`
- calls `qcmdexc` to run the `DSPOBJAUT` command with the output going to an `OUTFILE` in library `QTEMP`.
- use the SQL `select` statement to read the contents of the `DSPOBJAUT` outfile
- runs `json_encode` to echo the outfile contents to the web caller as a `json` stream.

```
<?php

// set out document type to text/javascript instead of text/html
header("Content-type: text/javascript; charset:utf-8;");

$objName  = isset($_GET["objName"]) ? $_GET["objName"]: '' ; 
$objLib  = isset($_GET["objLib"]) ? $_GET["objLib"]: '' ; 
$objType  = isset($_GET["objType"]) ? $_GET["objType"]: '' ; 

// connect to ibm i 
$libl = 'qgpl qtemp' ;
$options = array('i5_naming' => DB2_I5_NAMING_ON);  
$options['i5_libl'] = $libl ;       // library names separated by space.
$conn = db2_connect("*LOCAL","","", $options);
if (!$conn)
{
  echo db2_conn_errormsg() ;
}

// build and run dspobjaut command. Will output object authorities to file in qtemp.
$cmds = 'dspobjaut obj(' . $objLib . '/' . $objName . ') objtype(' . $objType . ') output(*outfile) outfile(qtemp/objaut)';
$sql = "call  qcmdexc('" . $cmds . "', " . strlen($cmds) . ")" ;
$stmt = db2_prepare( $conn, $sql ) ;
$result = db2_execute( $stmt ) ;

// read contents of dspobjaut outfile. Read into array where each item 
// contains object. Each property of object is column from the dspobjaut outfile table.
$sql = 'select a.* from qtemp/objaut a ' ;
$stmt = db2_prepare( $conn, $sql ) ;
$result = db2_execute( $stmt ) ;
$ar1 = db2Stmt_ToManyRowArray($stmt) ;

// return dspobjaut output as json data stream.
$encode_txt = json_encode( $ar1, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ) ;
echo   $encode_txt ;

// --------------------- db2Stmt_GetColNames ----------------
// build and return array of column names from a db2_execute
// executed $stmt.
function db2Stmt_GetColNames( $stmt )
{
  $colCx = db2_num_fields($stmt);
  $colNames = array( ) ;
  for( $ix=0; $ix < $colCx; $ix++ )
  {
    array_push( $colNames, db2_field_name( $stmt, $ix )) ;
  }
  return  $colNames ;
}

// ------------------- db2Stmt_ToManyRowArray ------------
function db2Stmt_ToManyRowArray( $stmt )
{
  $colNames = db2Stmt_GetColNames( $stmt ) ;
  $manyArr = array( ) ;
  while( $row = db2_fetch_array( $stmt ))
  {

  // build row array consisting of column name/vlu pairs for
  // each column of the result set.
    $rowArr = array( ) ;
    for( $ix = 0 ; $ix < count($colNames) ; $ix++ )
    {
      $rowArr[ $colNames[$ix] ] = rtrim($row[$ix]) ;
    }

  // push the $rowArr onto the array of many rows.
    $manyArr[] = $rowArr ;
  }

  return $manyArr ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, for now I don't have PHP in the machine but I will take note on this. Thank.